# geometric meaning of Ricci-flatness

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What is the geometric meaning of Ricci-flatness?
We know that if the Riemann tensor at a point vanished, manifold is flat at this point. but I don't know When the Ricci tensor vanished at a point, what is shape of manifold at this point? and a same question about scalar curvature.

Comment: Why didn't you search a little bit before asking this? It's clearly explained on Wikipedia!

Comment: I have searched this, but what is on wikipedia is very short and does not convince me.

Comment: It means to second order the there is no volume distortion by the exponential map.   Is there something specific you would like to know?